# Google Analytics Implementation with Winter '16 Update

Tags: apex, visualforce, community, winter16

Before Winter '16 update in the Kokua community template, we use Site.com to insert our Google Analytics tracking script into the Head section of the template.

Now that the Winter '16 update no longer uses Site.com, our Google Analytics linkage is no longer functional.

What is the proper way to add our Google Analytics script to the Kokua template? Does a lightning component / any other sccript  need to be created with the tracking script and added to each page in the template?